# "BIOS" Socket on Ethernet Cards

Tags: bios, ethernet

Hey, I have two Ethernet Cards flying round here.
Both of them have a Socket for a ROM Chip (one with EPROM Socket, the other one PLCC Socket).

Whats the Purpose of those?
Can I use it to reconfigure another BIOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to hold a boot ROM, with a RPL, PXE, or some other similar code image for the card.

Comment: does the bios i plug onto that card has to be of the same type of bios thats on the mainboard, or is this a special configuration?

Comment: No, it's specific to the CPU family and the NIC itself.